# RegEx to extract parenthesis and function name

Tags: javascript, regex

Somebody help me to write RegEx for the following cases

- somestring() => `['somestring']`
- somestring()[10] => `['somestring','',10]`
- somestring('argString') => `['somestring', 'argString']`
- somestring('argString')[10] =>`['somestring', 'argString',10]`
- somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'}) => `['somestring', {prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'}]`
- somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'})[100] => `['somestring', {prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'},100]`

This is I tried so far

```
var regExp = /\b[^()]+\((.*)\)+\[(.*?)]/;
var matches = regExp.exec('somestring()[10]');
```

Comment: Why are you using regexp to decode what looks like JS? What are you planning to do with the results? Do you need to handle something like `somestring(foo(bar))`, or `somestring(foo[10](bar))`, or `somestring(foo(bar)[10])`, or `somestring({prop1: foo(bar)[10]})`?

Comment: @torazaburo  inside paranthesis anything can be there, my only concern is to just get the content inside the paranthesis

Comment: In that case it is going to be very hard to do with regexp, since regexp does not deal well with nested syntax. Can you add such an example to our question so that other people answering have test cases to work against? A little tiny parser might work better for you.

Comment: @torazaburo I have mentioned all my use cases in the question, nothing more

Comment: On the one hand you say "inside parentheses anything can be there", which implies that it could include additional nested parentheses or brackets, but then you say "I have mentioned all my use cases, nothing more". Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could work:

```
var input = ['somestring()', 'somestring()[10]', "somestring('argString')", "somestring('argString')[10]", "somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'})", "somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'})[100]"];

console.log(input.map(function(v) {
  let result = v.match(/(.*)\((.*)\)(\[([^\]]*)\])?/);

  return [result[1], result[2], result[4]];
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can negate `(`,`)`, `[`, `]` from matches

```
let re = /[^()\[\]]+/g;

let res = "somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'})[100]".match(re);
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to add empty value if there is no argument in function paranthesis ?

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to exclude the closing brackets:

```
var regExp = /\b[^()]+\(([^)]*)\)(\[[^\]]*\])?/;
```

This will break if you have a string like the following though:

```
somestring({myKey: myFunc()})[myArray[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to handle this with `Proxy`, as follows:

```js
const somestring = new Proxy(() => {}, {
  apply(target, thisArg, [arg = '']) {
    return new Proxy(['somestring', arg], {
      get(target, prop) {
        if (!isNaN(String(prop))) return [...target, prop];
        return target[prop];
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(
  somestring(),
  somestring()[10],
  somestring('argString'),
  somestring('argString')[10],
  somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'}),
  somestring({prop1:'v1',prop2:'v2'})[100]
);
```

This works properly in node, but not in the Chrome devtools console, because the latter apparently tries to invoke the `get` on each element when serializing to the console using `console.log`.

Node output:

```
[ 'somestring', '' ] 
[ 'somestring', '', '10' ] 
[ 'somestring', 'argString' ] 
[ 'somestring', 'argString', '10' ] 
[ 'somestring', { prop1: 'v1', prop2: 'v2' } ] 
[ 'somestring', { prop1: 'v1', prop2: 'v2' }, '100' ]
```

The basic idea here is to create a function proxy, which when invoked (`apply`) returns the `['somestring', arg]` array, but also wrap a proxy around that which traps property accesses (`get`) such as `[10]`, and return `['somestring', arg, 10]` in that case.